# Iterating an R Script as a function of sequential survey questions

Tags: r, survey

The function below works perfectly for my purpose. The display is wonderful. Now my problem is I need to be able to do it again, many times, on other variables that fit other patterns.

In this example, I've output results for "q4a", I would like to be able to do it for sequences of questions that follow patterns like: q4 < a - z > or q < 4 - 10 >< a - z >, automagically.

Is there some way to iterate this such that the specified variable (in this case q4a) changes each time?

Here's my function:

```
require(reshape) # Using it for melt
require(foreign) # Using it for read.spss

d1 <- read.spss(...) ## Read in SPSS file

attach(d1,warn.conflicts=F) ## Attach SPSS data

q4a_08 <- d1[,grep("q4a_",colnames(d1))] ## Pull in everything matching q4a_X
q4a_08 <- melt(q4a_08) ## restructure data for post-hoc

detach(d1)

q4aaov <- aov(formula=value~variable,data=q4a) ## anova
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share a sample of what is in d1 so that we can better understand the problem?

Comment: d1 is survey data from a SPSS file. The survey has n=485 respondents asked about 24 questions that are all numeric responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but to generate the list of questions:

```
> gsub('^', 'q', gsub(' ', '', 
    apply(expand.grid(1:10,letters),1,
           function(r) paste(r, sep='', collapse='')
         )))
  [1] "q1a"  "q2a"  "q3a"  "q4a"  "q5a"  "q6a"  "q7a"  "q8a"  "q9a"  "q10a"
 [11] "q1b"  "q2b"  "q3b"  "q4b"  "q5b"  "q6b"  "q7b"  "q8b"  "q9b"  "q10b"
 [21] "q1c"  "q2c"  "q3c"  "q4c"  "q5c"  "q6c"  "q7c"  "q8c"  "q9c"  "q10c"
 [31] "q1d"  "q2d"  "q3d"  "q4d"  "q5d"  "q6d"  "q7d"  "q8d"  "q9d"  "q10d"
 [41] "q1e"  "q2e"  "q3e"  "q4e"  "q5e"  "q6e"  "q7e"  "q8e"  "q9e"  "q10e"
 [51] "q1f"  "q2f"  "q3f"  "q4f"  "q5f"  "q6f"  "q7f"  "q8f"  "q9f"  "q10f"
 [61] "q1g"  "q2g"  "q3g"  "q4g"  "q5g"  "q6g"  "q7g"  "q8g"  "q9g"  "q10g"
 [71] "q1h"  "q2h"  "q3h"  "q4h"  "q5h"  "q6h"  "q7h"  "q8h"  "q9h"  "q10h"
 [81] "q1i"  "q2i"  "q3i"  "q4i"  "q5i"  "q6i"  "q7i"  "q8i"  "q9i"  "q10i"
 [91] "q1j"  "q2j"  "q3j"  "q4j"  "q5j"  "q6j"  "q7j"  "q8j"  "q9j"  "q10j"
 ...
```

And then you turn your inner part of the analysis into a function that takes the question prefix as a parameter:

```
analyzeQuestion <- function (prefix)
{
  q <- d1[,grep(prefix,colnames(d1))] ## Pull in everything matching q4a_X
  q <- melt(q) ## restructure data for post-hoc

  qaaov <- aov(formula=value~variable,data=q4a) ## anova
  return (LTukey(q4aaov,which="",conf.level=0.95)) ## Tukey's post-hoc
}
```

Now - I'm not sure where your 'q4a' variable is coming from (as used in the `aov(..., data=q4a)`- so not sure what to do about that bit. But hopefully this helps.

To put the two together you can use `sapply()` to apply the `analyzeQuestion` function to each of the prefixes that we automagically generated.

Comment: I'm going to try this one out.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend melting the entire dataset and then splitting `variable` into its component pieces.  Then you can more easily use subset to look at (e.g.) just question four: `subset(molten, q = 4)`.

Comment: There are some examples of this in the introduction to reshape: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper

Comment: Thanks for the link to the paper!